# Best approach loading a text file (.txt) to bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

Anyone got any pratical idea with regard to what is the best possible approach to upload a text file to a bigquery table? I have a few  zipped text files I need to download from a remote SFTP server and load it into a bigquery table. Should I download it to a google cloud storage and upload it from there to bigquery for faster speed? The text files are about 5GB each and will grow further.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this going to be a recurring task, or a one-time thing?

Comment: What is the size of your data in you local data source?

Comment: Sorry was supposed to mean text file .txt. Yes, it will be recurring load each month end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to consider if you are loading files from your local data source is that there are limitations for that, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#limitations).

> **Loading data from a local data source is subject to the following limitations:**
>
> Wildcards and comma separated lists are not supported when you load
> files from a local data source. Files must be loaded individually.
> When using the classic BigQuery web UI, files loaded from a local data
> source must be 10 MB or less and must contain fewer than 16,000 rows.

Besides that, with this provided above link , there are instructions how to upload your data with Console or CLI.

Nevertheless, using the cloud storage you can take advantage of long term storage, which means that you are not charged by loading data into bigquery instead for storing the data in Cloud Storage. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage#take_advantage_of_long-term_storage).

Finally, I would like you to consider two points [External and Natives tables in bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables-intro).

> **Native tables:** tables backed by native BigQuery storage.
>
> **External tables:** tables backed by storage external to BigQuery. For more
> information, see Querying External Data Sources.

In other words, using Native tables you import the full data inside BigQuery. Thus, it tends to me faster when executing data analysis. Meanwhile, external tables do not store data in BigQuery, instead references the data from an external source.

The [cost of storing in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) is higher than in [Cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing). Although, querying external tables is slower than querying against native tables, mainly if the files are significantly large. Lastly, since external tables are pointers to files, you do not have to wait for the data to load.